# Does python have overloaded parameters?

Tags: python, addition

How could I integrate multiple values as parameters without using a tuple or a list? Does python have overloaded parameters?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
add(1,2)      # 3
add(1,2,3,4)  # 10

def add(numbers):
    return sum(list(numbers))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [`*args` (argument lists)](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

Comment: The questions you've stated have nothing to do with your title. Please rewrite your title to address the question you are actually asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Arbitrary Argument List](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

However, you are probably doing more work than you need to and also I am not entirely sure what you are exactly trying to do (or what you mean by efficient algorithm), but the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) builtin function already does what you needed, you just need to read the documentation on what it actually expects in its arguments.

```
>>> sum([1,2,3])
6
>>> sum([1,2,3,4,5,6])
21
```

Or heck, if you want to go without a list or tuple (actually, arguments are a list already so you are just using unnecessary syntactic sugar) you can just do this then.

```
def add(*numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

Just think a little and you can put together the above function.

Comment: Your second example is exactly what I needed. Thanks!